# Windows IIS Server - Public IP not working - showing gateway timeout error

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, iis-7.5

I have a Windows server setup and have assigned a public IP address to it. Ports 80 and 443 are open and confirmed by a networking team. I have checked the Windows Firewall with advanced settings and port 80 is allowed on the inbound rules.

When typing the public ip in a browser, instead of showing the IIS welcome page it displays a 504 Gateway Timeout error - The requested URL couldn't be resolved.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be great.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the networking configuration since the fact that you are getting an HTTP error code clearly shows that the server is answering the client from which you are connecting.

Error 504 directs us in another direction. The message hints that the server is being configured as a proxy for another server which would be serving the requested URL. Your server could not get an answer from that other server in a timely manner resulting in the error you are seeing.

Let's call your IIS `server-a` and the other one in the background `server-b`

This normaly means either:

- `server-b` is offline
- `server-b` is on a slow network connection, under heavy load, or the serving of the page you requested takes longer for `server-b` to do than `server-a` is willing to wait.